# How to fix addEventListener in my code? It seems like it's being canceled at any time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a grid with a determined number of squares inside a container. I have used a function with a default 16x16 squares and added an EventListener (mouseover) to add a class to any div. It works perfectly when I first refresh the page. The problem is that when I want to reset the number of squares with a personalized function, my code do the job, but the EventListener stops working. Any Help Here?

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');

const buttonsDiv = document.querySelector('#buttons-div');

setGrid();

function resetGrid() {
    clearGrid();

    while (container.firstChild) {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    };

    let numberOfsquares = prompt('Number of squares??? 1-64:');
    return setGrid(numberOfsquares);
}

function setGrid(numberOfsquares = 16) {
    let heightAndWidth = 960 / numberOfsquares;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfsquares; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfsquares; j++) {
            const divNode = document.createElement('div');
            divNode.classList.add('unit');
            divNode.style.width = heightAndWidth + 'px';
            divNode.style.height = heightAndWidth + 'px';
            container.appendChild(divNode);
        }
    }
    return numberOfsquares;
}

function clearGrid() {
    squares.forEach((square) => {
        square.classList.remove('hover');
    });
}

let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.unit');
squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        console.log('listened');
        square.classList.add('hover');
    });
});

const clearButton = document.createElement('button');
clearButton.textContent = 'Clear';
clearButton.classList.add('reset-button');
clearButton.setAttribute('id', 'clearButton');
buttonsDiv.appendChild(clearButton);

const resetButton = document.createElement('button');
resetButton.textContent = 'Reset';
resetButton.classList.add('reset-button');
resetButton.setAttribute('id', 'resetButton');
buttonsDiv.appendChild(resetButton);

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (button.id === 'clearButton') {
            clearGrid();
        } else if (button.id === 'resetButton') {
            resetGrid();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `resetGrid` removes all the elements that had event listeners added ... you'd need to attach event listeners to the newly created elements (the `let squares` and `const buttons` code that runs exactly once in your code

Comment: in which case you just need to move those two blocks of code that @JaromandaX mentioned into functions to run at the end of setGrid(), then call setGrid() inside resetGrid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments. The `resetGrid` function removes the elements from the DOM, so the attached Event Listener wont be called any more, since the Element just does not exist anymore. I recommend to use "event delegation" for this. So attach the Event Listener to the `container` and use `e.target` witin the callback to figure out which item was hit.

```
container.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  const { target } = e;
  //use the child index for instance, or add col and row using a data attribute
})
```